# please help me for loop c++ i don't to run it

Tags: c++

i can't to write a code to for loop c++
I want it to be

```
1
21
321
4321
```

But I do not write that way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            cout<<j;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

it outputs:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
```

Comment: (1) you need to fix your tabbing. Its very hard to read this. (2) try reversing the inner loop - instead of counting up (j++) count down (j--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your second loop like this:

```
 for(int j=i; j>=1; j--)
```

and it will work.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/3DMggs)

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but replace your 
    `for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)`
with
    `for(int j=i; j>0; j--)`